# Shell script sed - replace numbers

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a file that contains address, name and phone number.

Original line:

```
Elizabeth Salnger 117 Someone St - Fresno, CA013023459876AcccountActive
```

Expected line:

```
Elizabeth Salnger 117 Someone St - Fresno, CA099999999999AcccountActive
```

I have a function

```
sed -r 's/./&\n/64;s//\n&/52;:a;s/(\n.[0-9]+)[0-9](.*\n)/\1P\2/;ta;s/\n//g'
```

Obs: this function is used to convert various files, that's why I have to set position on sed function.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to do. I think you could add more examples and expected results.

Comment: @HugoTeixeira - updated question with original and expect result.

Comment: You've got to tell us what it is you're trying to do, don't rely on us figuring out your intent by reading your code that I'm assuming doesn't do what you want and then working backwards from that.

Comment: I want to replece phone number. I got 013023459876 and I want 099999999999.

Comment: If `sed 's/013023459876/099999999999/'` isn't all you need then try again to explain your requirements and please put that explanation in your question rather then adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you look for but you can try this sed :

```
sed -E 's/(.*,[^0-9]*)[0-9]*(.*)/\1099999999999\2/' infile
```

If it's ok, i can add explanation.